# Pyppeteer session crash or Timeout Exceeded

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu-20.04, pyppeteer

For the purpose of scraping binance.com, I use the library
pyppeteer to render the web page and get clean html code instead of javascript code.

My problem is this: the first time the session works properly on the remote Ubuntu 20.04 server, but when I run the code again I get **pyppeteer.errors.PageError: Page crashed!** or **pyppeteer.errors.TimeoutError: Navigation Timeout Exceeded: 100000 ms exceeded.** Moreover, the code works when I run it in PyCharm from my main Windows system, but the problems happen exactly on ubuntu.

I think the problem has something to do with unclaimed pyppeteer sessions, but I'm not sure.

Here is my code:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from datetime import datetime
from sql import *


if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        session = HTMLSession()
        r = session.get('https://www.binance.com/ru/trade/ETH_BTC')
        r.html.render(sleep = 1, keep_page=True, scrolldown=1, timeout=1000)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.html.html, "lxml")

        price = soup.find("div", class_ = lambda value: value and value.startswith("showPrice"))


        now = datetime.now()
        dt_string = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
        sql(dt_string, price.text)
        print(dt_string + " ETH/BTC: " +  price.text)

        r.close()
        session.close()
```

Here is the crash error log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "binance.py", line 13, in <module>
    r.html.render(sleep = 1, keep_page=True, scrolldown=1, timeout=1000)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/requests_html.py", line 598, in render
    content, result, page = self.session.loop.run_until_complete(self._async_render(url=self.url, script=script, sleep=sleep, wait=wait, content=self.html, reload=reload, scrolldown=scrolldown, timeout=timeout, keep_page=keep_page))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/requests_html.py", line 512, in _async_render
    await page.goto(url, options={'timeout': int(timeout * 1000)})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyppeteer/page.py", line 885, in goto
    raise error
pyppeteer.errors.TimeoutError: Navigation Timeout Exceeded: 1000000 ms exceeded.
[E:pyppeteer.connection] connection unexpectedly closed
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-105' coro=<Connection._async_send() done, defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyppeteer/connection.py:69> exception=InvalidStateError('invalid state')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/websockets/protocol.py", line 827, in transfer_data
    message = await self.read_message()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/websockets/protocol.py", line 895, in read_message
    frame = await self.read_data_frame(max_size=self.max_size)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/websockets/protocol.py", line 971, in read_data_frame
    frame = await self.read_frame(max_size)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/websockets/protocol.py", line 1047, in read_frame
    frame = await Frame.read(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/websockets/framing.py", line 105, in read
    data = await reader(2)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/streams.py", line 721, in readexactly
    raise exceptions.IncompleteReadError(incomplete, n)
asyncio.exceptions.IncompleteReadError: 0 bytes read on a total of 2 expected bytes

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyppeteer/connection.py", line 73, in _async_send
    await self.connection.send(msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/websockets/protocol.py", line 555, in send
    await self.ensure_open()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/websockets/protocol.py", line 803, in ensure_open
    raise self.connection_closed_exc()
websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedError: code = 1006 (connection closed abnormally [internal]), no reason

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyppeteer/connection.py", line 79, in _async_send
    await self.dispose()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyppeteer/connection.py", line 170, in dispose
    await self._on_close()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyppeteer/connection.py", line 151, in _on_close
    cb.set_exception(_rewriteError(
asyncio.exceptions.InvalidStateError: invalid state
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-2' coro=<Connection._recv_loop() done, defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyppeteer/connection.py:53> exception=PageError('Page crashed!')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyppeteer/connection.py", line 61, in _recv_loop
    await self._on_message(resp)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyppeteer/connection.py", line 143, in _on_message
    self._on_query(msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyppeteer/connection.py", line 123, in _on_query
    session._on_message(params.get('message'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyppeteer/connection.py", line 276, in _on_message
    self.emit(obj.get('method'), obj.get('params'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyee/_base.py", line 108, in emit
    handled = self._call_handlers(event, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyee/_base.py", line 91, in _call_handlers
    self._emit_run(f, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyee/_compat.py", line 49, in _emit_run
    coro = f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyppeteer/page.py", line 205, in <lambda>
    lambda event: self._onTargetCrashed())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyppeteer/page.py", line 228, in _onTargetCrashed
    self.emit('error', PageError('Page crashed!'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyee/_base.py", line 111, in emit
    self._emit_handle_potential_error(event, args[0] if args else None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyee/_base.py", line 83, in _emit_handle_potential_error
    raise error
pyppeteer.errors.PageError: Page crashed!
```

Comment: It works well after rebooting Windows, but ONLY for the first time. I cant find a solution

Answer (score 0):

It works well again for second, third, etc times if u KILL a process, for example, using **killall -9 python3**. Task solved!

Comment: I bet a problem is connected with some unused pyppeteer chromium cache